# Where can I find up-to-date information / walkthroughs on VS 2010 deployment?

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2010, msdeploy

I am looking for information on deploying my web app to our test server. Having heard Hanselman say this is something you can do within VS 2010 easily I set out too find information on exactly how to do this but can not seem to find anything.

Ignoring the fact that most of the blog posts / articles are over a year old, there just seems to be no clear step by step information on how to do this.

Has anyone found the light? where did you learn this information?

---

Best resources i have found so far:-
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120710063032/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/02/04/web-deployment-with-vs-2010-and-iis.aspx)
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120623112017/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/03/10/how-does-web-deployment-with-vs10-and-msdeploy-work.aspx)

Many thanks,
Kohan

Comment: Im having the same issue.

Trying to figure out how to execute the YUI Compressor (CSS/JS Minification) as a post-build task in VS2010. Having no such luck a) getting it to work or b) finding any posts that detail how to do it...the search continues...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More to the pipe, these MSDN blog links:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/tags/web+deployment/
- https://web.archive.org/web/20120702130644/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/webdevtools/archive/2010/05/26/visual-studio-2010-web-deployment-projects-rtw-available-now.aspx
- https://web.archive.org/web/20120629025549/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/webdevtools/archive/2010/04/22/web-deployment-excluding-files-and-folders-via-the-web-application-s-project-file.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Found this on SO.

[How can I get TFS2010 to run MSDEPLOY for me through MSBUILD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636153/how-can-i-get-tfs2010-to-run-msdeploy-for-me-through-msbuild)

The poster mentions 2 good links ...
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebDeploymentMadeAwesomeIfYoureUsingXCopyYoureDoingItWrong.aspx
 http://microsoftpdc.com/Sessions/FT56?type=wmv

and
http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/FT14