# Visual Studio Publish Web Deploy getting ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, webdeploy

I've read through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807049/webdeploy-401-unauthorized-error), which seems to have a similar issue, however the error message is different. I tried the solutions listed there to no avail.

Here's the rub. I have 2 apps that are both publishing to this `VM`. An older `ASP.NET 4.6 app` which publishes just fine... without any problem at all and the new `ASP.NET Core` app which does have the problem. I am using the same settings in the publish of the new app as the old app, except the `Site name` which is only different as `Default Web Site/OldSite` to `Default Web Site/NewSite`. The publish fails. I can manually `dotnet publish` then copy the "publish" files manually to the `VM` and that works fine. Is this a problem with the `ASP.NET Core` `publish template` or am I missing something?

Yes, I verified that the user I am trying to connect with is `Administrator` in both `Windows Users` and `Active Directory Admin group`. I've also changed the `WMSVC` to run under the same admin user. In my `publish settings` `User name` I've tried both with `domain\username` and `username`. Both show a green check mark when I try to `Validate Connection`. I am not completely blocked as I can keep manually running `dotnet publish` and manually copying, but an actual fix fr this would make my life a bit easier. Please help.

The actual error I get is:

```
Error count: 1.

More Information: Connected to 'myvm.westus.cloudapp.azure.com' using the
Web Deployment Agent Service, but could not authorize. Make sure you are an 
administrator on 'myvm.westus.cloudapp.azure.com'.  Learn more at:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN.

Error Code: ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN

Error: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

Comment: I know this is an old question and i saw you already have resolved the issue in Github. However, I'm encountering the same issue and followed the solution provided but still getting the same error. If you still remember this, can you provide to me the command that you used?

Comment: I don't remember but I think `Verifying the Connection` in the publish settings before the publish, might be enough...

Answer (score 3):

This answer will not solve OP's question but it might provides help for others that face similar error.

In my case I was able to deploy application to the remote server via Visual Studio. However will face `Error Code: ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN` when trying to deploy using `dotnet publish`.

Below is the command line that I used to deploy the application to the remote server successfully:

```sh
dotnet publish HelloWorld.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /p:PublishProfile=IISProfile.pubxml /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:UserName=username /p:Password=password
```

At first I thought that by just pointing to the `.pubxml` file already sufficient enough and it will automatically use the credentials in these two files `.pubxml` and `.pubxml.user`. Oh boy, I was wrong. Took me 2 days to figure out my mistake.