# How to write MSBuild Arguments without a username and password when deploying to IIS7 using WMSVC and NTLM Auth?

Tags: iis-7, msbuild, tfsbuild, webdeploy

I've been trying to get our web app auto-deployed using TFS/MSBuild with WMSVC. **The problem is that I can't use a build script that exposes a password**. I'm hoping that I can take the identity that the build server is using to authenticate with WMSVC on my IIS 7.5 machine and get the app deployed with all the web.config goodness that has been promised.

There is another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639597/how-do-i-deploy-using-msdeploy-in-team-build-2010-using-the-wmsvc-service-and-nt) that offers work-arounds and states that WMSVC defaults to BASIC auth and to encrypt the password. This isn't something we want to do. Our requirements are to do a deploy without embedding user/pwd into the build scripts.

We want to be able to use NTLM via delegation or adding the build server to the administrator group on the IIS machine.

Is this totally impossible? There is no way to do this without a username and password specified in the build script? I just want the credentials I have already assigned on the IIS side for my build server to work. Any idea if this is just simply wishful thinking?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the *-authType NTLM* flag in the msdeploy command line [described here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569001%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:webServer,wmsvc=Server1,authtype=NTLM
```